# Two specific user_type match the user laravel

Tags: laravel

```
$credentials = array(
                'email' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'active' => 1,
                'type' => 1, 2
            );
```

check if type 1 exist then allow to login if user_type 1 does not exist with username and password combination check from two if exist login without none user found;

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
    //Something
}
```

Comment: override the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in `Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

Comment: You misuse [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication) with [authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization). Those two are different, so try to keep the authentication simple and add some policies for the authorization.

Comment: what to update and where

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, true)) {
   if(Auth::user()->type==1){
      //write logic here
   }else{
     //write logic here
   }
}
```